# Remove Space at end of String but keep new line symbol

Tags: python, regex, whitespace, removing-whitespace

How can I check if a Python string at any point has **a single space before new line**? And if it does, I have to remove that single space, but keep the new line symbol. Is this possible?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're talking about strings like `'my test string'`, `'my test string '`, and `'my test string \n`, right? And you want to turn them into either `'my test string'` or `'my test string\n'`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I want to check if a Python string at any point has a single space before new line? And if it does, I have to remove that single space, but keep the new line symbol. Is this possible?

Comment: Okay; my answer should take care of that.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 There are a few problems. Strings might have only one character in them, so doing something like string[-2] would be out of bounds.

Comment: What if that one character is a space?

Comment: did you want to replace the space before last newline character with empty string?

Comment: So you want strings that end with two spaces to end with one space after this script runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def remspace(my_str):
    if len(my_str) < 2: # returns ' ' unchanged
        return my_str
    if my_str[-1] == '\n':
        if my_str[-2] == ' ':
            return my_str[:-2] + '\n'
    if my_str[-1] == ' ':
        return my_str[:-1]
    return my_str
```

Results:

```
>>> remspace('a b c')
'a b c'
>>> remspace('a b c ')
'a b c'
>>> remspace('a b c\n')
'a b c\n'
>>> remspace('a b c \n')
'a b c\n'
>>> remspace('')
''
>>> remspace('\n')
'\n'
>>> remspace(' \n')
'\n'
>>> remspace(' ')
' '
>>> remspace('I')
'I'
```

Comment: str[-2] might be out of bounds though. I'm looking at a are variety of strings. Some of them may even be something like: "I\n"

Comment: This is really close. The string may also be something like: "I"

Comment: How about if the string is `' '`, a single space? `if len(str) > 1 and str[-1] == ' ':` rather than `if str[-1] == ' ':` results in returning the single space. If you prefer that it turn `' '` into the empty string, use the latter.

Comment: Please don't use `str`... when I see it - all I can think is the builtin `str`... call it `text` or something - shadowing a built-in name is never good practice :(

Comment: Funny story: I was consciously attempting to avoid using `string`, and blundered right into `str`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 been there done that... at least `string` is slightly better - as it's more likely someone wants to use `str` than the `string` module... but six of one, half dozen of the other etc...

Comment: Well, I'm sure that `my_str` is available - after all, I clearly scrawled "MINE!" on it.

Comment: @ninja_power: this code was for the original, unedited question that specified the end of the string. To handle `' \n'` appearing anywhere in the string, use `my_str.replace(' \n', '\n')` as per Malonge's answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about just replacing the specific instance of ' \n' with '\n'?

```
s1 = 'This is a test \n'
s1.replace(' \n', '\n') 
>>> 'This is a test\n'

s2 = 'There is no trailing space here\n'
s2.replace(' \n', '\n')
>>> 'There is no trailing space here\n'
```

Comment: What if `' \n'` occurs somewhere other than the end of the string?

Comment: Interesting point, although I don't see how this opposes the specifications of the question. Wouldn't it still achieve the desired goal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strip multiple spaces, you can use regex:

```
import re

def strip_trailing_space(my_string):
    return re.sub(r' +(\n|\Z)', r'\1', my_string)

def strip_trailing_whitespace(my_string):
    return re.sub(r'[ \t]+(\n|\Z)', r'\1', my_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Input File:

filea.txt (With many spaces)

dragon
dragonballs

### test.py

filea = open('filea.txt','r')
fileb = open('fileb.txt','a')
for line in filea:
for i in range(len(line)):
if ' \n' in line:
line = line.replace(' \n','\n')
fileb.write(line)

### op:

### fileb.txt

dragon
dragonballs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).