# Remove single white space from end of lines for .TXT file

Tags: python, file, whitespace

I'm trying to use Python to open a .txt file and remove a single white space if it exists from the end of each line, BUT all the new lines and formatting has to remain. **I need to check each individual line in the .txt file and if there are any lines with a single space at the end, I need to remove just that single space for those lines, that's it. Everything else must remain intact.** Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What code do you have so far? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: What if there are more than one spaces?

Comment: @thefourtheye That will never occur. There will either just be one space, or none.

Comment: @fjarri I have an entire program that outputs to a .txt file, but these white spaces are the only issue I'm having when I output my new .txt file.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Do you know how to split your file contents into lines? Do you know how to check if a line ends with a space? Do you know how to remove the last character from a line? Do you know how to join the lines back into a single string? If you know all that, you know how to solve your problem.

Comment: See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111443/remove-space-at-end-of-string-but-keep-new-line-symbol/29111556).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 No this is a difference scenario.

Comment: Why not avoid outputting the spaces in the first place? `' '.join()` is often helpful. Can you show how you are writing the file? or a similar example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not something like:

```
for line in input_file:
    if line.endswith(" \n"):
       line = line.replace(' \n', '\n')
```

Followed by whatever steps you take to collect the reviewed/modified inputs for later outputting.

There may be a cleverer way to do it, but this should work.

Editted to reflect a more readable fix.

Comment: Maybe `line = line.replace(' \n', '\n')`? If it's coming from a text file, there shouldn't be more than one `'\n'` per line.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - good point. Not sure it will matter for performance, but it does improve readability.